# How to design tables and their hierarchy when using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and have been playing around with MongoDB with Node.js. I am developing a sample project to learn which is a issue tracker like github.

What I am not clear on is what approach to use when designing documents to store data.

**Option 1**

Coming from a relational model world, I found it very natural to created documents like

- Projects { id, name}
- ProjectUserMapping {id, projectid, userid}
- Issues {id, projectid, name, blah, blah.. }

and so on.

**Option 2**

After reading few articles here and there on internet, I found people using something on this line

```
Project {
 Users ['yasser', 'neel', 'ian'],
 Issues [
  {'how do I turn this on', '22/12/2014'...'}
 ]
```

Which is the better approach, considering the following 
- A lot of projects and each project will have a lot of issues, tags, filters and so on
- Query time. For example if I need to do a generic search of issues. Do i need to scan across issues under all projects since unlike previously now I dont have a separate issues table.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: Found this http://openmymind.net/Multiple-Collections-Versus-Embedded-Documents/#1

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a loaded question but the best starting point would be here:

[Mongo data structures](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/)

Without knowing the size/scale you want to obtain, a list of all queries you will be running, available hardware, and desires performance levels it would be difficult to give you more information.

But starting by making a list of queries you will be running and then creating data structures that allow you to efficiently run those queries (see link above) seems smart.

Also, mongo likes to store and access data from memory so having enough memory to store the data for your common queries is always highly recommended.